# Parsing HTML value in Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

This is a snippet of the HTML I have:

```
<body>
    <form method="post" action="./pagam.aspx?a=9095709&amp;b=RkVsgP1UClEdbu0oUvc8pKDxd5OcslXk1xHlVhK7uuqH_7ZfaquNNa1VHgeSZWm9hAq4s7Thk6wIhoRsooDoMF7U2nzmVDDbRujlxaPTg8I" id="aspnetForm" autocomplete="off">
<div>
```

I would like to extract this value:

```
./pagam.aspx?a=9095709&amp;b=RkVsgP1UClEdbu0oUvc8pKDxd5OcslXk1xHlVhK7uuqH_7ZfaquNNa1VHgeSZWm9hAq4s7Thk6wIhoRsooDoMF7U2nzmVDDbRujlxaPTg8I
```

from the HTML.

I currently have this as unsure how to do it:

```
parsed_html = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
a = parsed_html.body.find('div', attrs={'form method':'post'})
print (a)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
r = re.compile('action="\S+"')
r.match(line)
line[r.start():r.end()].split("=")
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is something you can try :

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> s = BeautifulSoup('<body>
<form method="post" name="mainForm" action="./pagam.aspx?a=9095709&amp;b=RkVsgP1UClEdbu0oUvc8pKDxd5OcslXk1xHlVhK7uuqH_7ZfaquNNa1VHgeSZWm9hAq4s7Thk6wIhoRsooDoMF7U2nzmVDDbRujlxaPTg8I" id="aspnetForm" autocomplete="off"></body>')
>>> s.find("form", {"name":"mainForm"})

>>> s.find("form", {"name":"mainForm"})['action']

u'./pagam.aspx?a=9095709&amp;b=RkVsgP1UClEdbu0oUvc8pKDxd5OcslXk1xHlVhK7uuqH_7ZfaquNNa1VHgeSZWm9hAq4s7Thk6wIhoRsooDoMF7U2nzmVDDbRujlxaPTg8I'
```